# Spring Boot WebClient OAuth - Got timeout when hit multiple request in same time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring boot (2.4.4) with webflux and oauth2-client, My code is success get from API server, when I hit using postman got response time around 500ms per hit. But when I hit with 10-100 data in same time using jMeter it cause error timeout. Is my code wrong or I miss something in my code?

Here is my OAuth config:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().authorizationCode().refreshToken().build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return authorizedClientManager;
}

@Bean
public WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("custom-registrationId");

    WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
    builder.defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    builder.filter(oauth);
    return builder.build();
}
```

The impementation on my webclient are using block, because I need to parsing the response from API before send to the client

```
@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

String response = webClient.post()
    .uri(URL_API)
    .bodyValue(jsonRequest)
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000))
    .share().block();
```

The problem is when I using jMeter. When i hit directly to API server everything is success, but not when through my Application

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 10000ms in 'flatMap' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

Comment: Dont use `block` In a `non-blocking` framework. Use `flatMap` or `map`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I don't know I could using that, because of this reactive framework I must not block everything right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Toerktumlare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840146/toerktumlare), I got enlightened how to write my code. So I think in this non-blocking framework better to write it like this instead of block()

```
Mono<String> response = webClient.post()
    .uri(URL_API)
    .bodyValue(jsonRequest)
    .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000));

Mono<Object> result = response.map(res -> {
    // Throw the logic parsing and other from response in here
})

return result;
```